# A quick question about showing that a sequence is increasing

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

For a sequence $a_n$ can we show that: $$a_n \leq a_{n+1} \iff \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq 1$$

Or a proof like this wouldn't be sufficient?

Comment: Assuming $a_n\ge 0$, then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\ge 1$ for all $n$.so the limit (if it exists) must be $\ge 1$.  However the converse is not true.  $a_n\gt a_{n+1}$ possible for some $n$.

Comment: Consider $(a_n)=1,1\frac12, 1, 1\frac14, 1, 1\frac16,1,1\frac18,...$

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your statement, written more precisely, is:

$$\exists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that }\ a_n \leq a_{n+1}\ \forall n \geq N \iff \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq 1.$$

$\ \Rightarrow\ $ is false because the limit may not exist. e.g. $1,1,2,2,4,4,8,8,16,16,32,32,64,64,...$. Here, $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ does not exist (it alternates between $1$ and $2$).

$\Leftarrow\ $ is also false, e.g. consider $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} = (\frac{1}{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}.$ Then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq 1,\ $ but $\nexists N \in \mathbb{N} \text{ such that }\ a_n \leq a_{n+1}\ \forall n \geq N.$

Comment: $\Leftarrow$ of $(2)$ is false. Consider $a_n=1+\frac 1n$.

Comment: Yes, I've changed my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, we better have $a_n>0$ for all $n$, or else we may have (additional) problems with some inequalities turning over.

Even then your suggested equivalence is far from true:

- If $a_n\le a_{n+1}$ for all $n$, then either $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a-n}\ge 1$ or the limit doesn't exist.
- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a-n}> 1$, then $a_n<a_{n+1}$ for all but finitely many $n$
- If $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= 1$, then it may be the case that $a_n\le a_{n+1}$ doesn't hold for any $n$ at all.

Concrete conunter examples:

- With $a_n=2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ we have $a_n\le a_{n+1}$ but $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ alternates between $1$ and $2$, hence the limit does not exist.
- With $a_n=n!$ we have $a_n\le a_{n+1}$ but $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=n\to\infty$ and again there i sno convergence. However, you way indeed want to allow $\lim=+\infty$ so this is perhaps not  a counterexample.
- For some (big) $N\in\Bbb N$, let $a_n=\max\{2^N-n,2^n\}$. Then  $\lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=2>1$, but $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for $1\le n<N-1$.
- Let $a_n=1+\frac1n$. Then $a_n>a_{n+1}$ for all $n$, but  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= 1$.